# sqlite query with like opearator is not working in xcode

Tags: xcode, sqlite, ios6

I wrote the code for sqlite statement as follows:

```
if(sqlite3_open([[self filepath] UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    retrievestatement = nil;

    if(retrievestatement == nil) {

        const char *sql = "Select * from OrdersHeaderTable where orderPlaceDate like '%?'";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &retrievestatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating detail view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }
    sqlite3_bind_text(retrievestatement, 1, [year UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    while(sqlite3_step(retrievestatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {

        NSLog(@"value is %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(retrievestatement, 0)]);

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(retrievestatement);
}
```

But it is not getting data.Please suggest me.

Comment: have you created the connection with the db? in which mode? if you post more code we can help you easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter marker `?` does not work inside strings.

You have to combine the string `'%'` and the *value* of your `year` parameter; this can be done either in your code (see Michele's answer), or in SQL like this:

```
sql = "Select * from OrdersHeaderTable where orderPlaceDate like '%' || ?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this line . I think this is the problem.

```
    const char *sql = "Select * from OrdersHeaderTable where orderPlaceDate like '%?'";
```

Change the above line to

```
    const char *sql = "Select * from OrdersHeaderTable where orderPlaceDate like '%hyd'";
```

i.e change the ? mark to your search string .

Comment: its works while I put statically but I need to append the value to that statement dynamically in place of ? then the above statement does not work for me.

Comment: Use the sqlite3_bind_Stmt like this  const char *insert = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO LIST (TERM, DEFINITION) VALUES (?, ?);";
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert, -1, &statement, nil);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [term UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [def UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_step(statement);
sqlite3_finalize(statement);

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way:

```
const char *sql = "Select * from OrdersHeaderTable where orderPlaceDate like ?001";
......
sqlite3_bind_text(retrieveStatement, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", year] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

I'm reporting here only the relevant part of code, add the prepare statement etc.